# Logarithmic x and y axis for image plot

Tags: plot, octave

I need to do this in a different way, since pcolor produces diagonal lines in the output file

```
h=pcolor(rand(16)); %The actual data comes from hist3
set(h,'EdgeColor','none');
colormap(gray(256));
set(gca,'yscale','log');
set(gca,'xscale','log');
print('test.png','-dpng','-r4800'); %Gives diagonal lines in text.png
```

Is there a simple workaround the bug. I use the FLTK backend.

### Update

Switching to gnuplot removes the diagonal lines, but adds vertical and horizontal lines, but changes increases the plot margins too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a "solution" to the bug. The idea is to disable anti-aliasing for graphics.

gswrapper.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

ARGS=()
ARGS+=("-dGraphicsAlphaBits=1")
for var in "$@"; do
    [ "$var" != '-dGraphicsAlphaBits=4' ] && ARGS+=("$var")
done
gs "${ARGS[@]}"
```

Octave script:

```
h=pcolor(rand(16)); %The actual data comes from hist3
set(h,'EdgeColor','none');
colormap(gray(256));
set(gca,'yscale','log');
set(gca,'xscale','log');
print('test.png','-dpng','-r600','-G./gswrapper.sh');
```